# Understanding KGf.CM in Camera Robotic Head Design

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, rotational-dynamics, torque

I am attempting to design a robotic camera head - however, I am struggling to calculate the torque (in terms of KGf.CM) I will require to rotate the Y (tilt) axis of the head.

The motor I intend to use is rated at 40KGf.cm at 30RPM - however, I do not know by how many centimetres I should divide the 40KG to determine my head capacity when factoring in the height of the camera and it's centre of mass.

To explain myself better, please see this image:

[image: Robo Head]

Considering the centre mass of the camera (let's say 10KG) exactly lines up with the motor, can I leave the the equation to stand at 1CM - or do I need to factor in the 10CM drop to the bottom of the camera basket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not being entirely unreasonable for wanting to calculate whether the motor will be strong enough to do what you're trying to do.  But, having quite a bit of experience in this area you're talking about, there are a couple of stumbling points I think you need to be aware of.

1. Motor ratings by the manufacturer are merely there to allow you to compare one motor to the next when purchasing them - they are nameplate ratings.  I suggest that you not even think for a minute that your motor will always output 40 KGf.CM under all circumstances (including yours).  Friction, non-ideal battery conditions, and the like can all give rise to very wide ranges of torque output from your motor.  Any calculations you arrive at with the numbers you have will probably not match reality very well.  You might consider getting your hands on a variety of motors and experimenting with them.
2. While we're on this topic, Google can convert KGf.cm into just about any other torque you are more comfortable working in, such as foot-pounds or Newton-meters should that make things easier.
3. If you want to calculate an estimated minimum torque rating for the motor, you'll need (1.) the mass of the camera and (2.) the distance from the rotation axis to the center of mass of the camera.  These two numbers, multiplied together, will give you the minimum torque needed to get the camera heat to begin to rotate.
4. It is a bit unclear to me what you mean by: ". . .to determine my head capacity when factoring in the height of the camera and it's centre of mass."
5. Again, I understand your wish to calculate these things before building a prototype, but remember that motor ratings are just estimates - you'll need quite a bit of prototyping and trial and error with motor ratings and torques to find a motor that will overcome the inertia of the camera, but not fling it around so fast as to risk damaging the camera.

Comment: It does appear that it's the old trial and error method then! 

Your comment in section two of your answer - "distance from rotation axis to the centre of mass of the camera" was indeed what I was assuming with my initial maths, but was seeking confirmation.

I am artificiality understating the performance of the motors I have selected as I am aware that they are guideline only - but fully agree trial and error would be the best way to proceed.